# Puppet ordering passenger install before ruby install

Tags: passenger, puppet

I am having some trouble with puppet executing the "install passenger" before the "install ruby" step. I have tried to set the order several ways, but I seem to be missing out on it. My eventual goal is to use this manifest for `vagrant up`

```ruby
[root@twdev01 ~]# uname -a
Linux twdev01 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@twdev01 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
[root@twdev01 ~]# puppet -V
3.0.2
```

Here is my manifest (which is based on https://gist.github.com/btisdall/3600897):

```ruby
[root@twdev01 ~]# cat /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp 
# Create TWDEV Environment

stage { 'req-install': before => Stage['rvm-install'] }

class misc {
    package {
        [
        'vim-enhanced', 'lsof', 'screen', 'lftp'
        ]:
        ensure => installed,
    }
}

class requirements {
  group { "puppet": ensure => "present", }
}

class seedRubyDownload {
    include seed-ruby-download
}

class installrvm {
  include rvm
  rvm::system_user { vagrant: ; }
}

class installruby {
    rvm_system_ruby {
        'ruby-1.9.3-p374':
        ensure      => 'present',
        default_use => true,
    }
}

class installpassenger { 
    class {
        'rvm::passenger::apache':
            version     => '3.0.19',
            ruby_version    => 'ruby-1.9.3-p374',
            mininstances    => '3',
            maxinstancesperapp  => '0',
            maxpoolsize     => '30',
            spawnmethod     => 'smart-lv2';
    }
}

class { requirements: stage => "req-install" }
class { installrvm: }
class { seedRubyDownload: before => Class[Installruby] }
class { installruby: require => Class[Installrvm] }
class { installpassenger: require => Class[Installruby] }
class { misc: }
#class { nginx: }
```

Here is the seed-ruby-download (only included for completeness):

```ruby
[root@twdev01 ~]# cat /etc/puppet/modules/seed-ruby-download/manifests/init.pp 
class seed-ruby-download {

  file {
    'ruby-source':
    ensure      => present,
    path        => '/usr/local/rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.3-p374.tar.bz2',
    source      => 'puppet:///modules/seed-ruby-download/ruby-1.9.3-p374.tar.bz2',
    mode        => '664',
    owner       => 'root',
    group       => 'rvm';

    'rubygems-source':
    ensure      => present,
    path        => '/usr/local/rvm/archives/rubygems-1.8.25.tgz',
    source      => 'puppet:///modules/seed-ruby-download/rubygems-1.8.25.tgz',
    mode        => '664',
    owner       => 'root',
    group       => 'rvm';

    'yaml-source':
    ensure      => present,
    path        => '/usr/local/rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz',
    source      => 'puppet:///modules/seed-ruby-download/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz',
    mode        => '664',
    owner       => 'root',
    group       => 'rvm';

  }
}
```

Here is the output of `puppet apply -v --debug /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`:

```ruby
[root@twdev01 ~]# puppet apply -v --debug /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/firewall/lib/facter/iptables.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/rvm/lib/facter/rvm_installed.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm from rvm into production
Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
Debug: hiera(): Hiera YAML backend starting
Debug: hiera(): Looking up rvm::install_rvm in YAML backend
Debug: hiera(): Looking for data source common
Debug: hiera(): Cannot find datafile /var/lib/hiera/common.yaml, skipping
Debug: hiera(): Looking up rvm::version in YAML backend
Debug: hiera(): Looking for data source common
Debug: hiera(): Cannot find datafile /var/lib/hiera/common.yaml, skipping
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/dependencies.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::dependencies from rvm/dependencies into production
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/dependencies/centos.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::dependencies::centos from rvm/dependencies/centos into production
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -ql rpm'
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -ql rpm'
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/system.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::system from rvm/system into production
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/system_user.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::system_user from rvm/system_user into production
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/seed-ruby-download/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported seed-ruby-download from seed-ruby-download into production
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/passenger/apache.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::passenger::apache from rvm/passenger/apache into production
Debug: hiera(): Looking up rvm::passenger::apache::poolidletime in YAML backend
Debug: hiera(): Looking for data source common
Debug: hiera(): Cannot find datafile /var/lib/hiera/common.yaml, skipping
Debug: hiera(): Looking up rvm::passenger::apache::rvm_prefix in YAML backend
Debug: hiera(): Looking for data source common
Debug: hiera(): Cannot find datafile /var/lib/hiera/common.yaml, skipping
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/passenger/apache/centos/pre.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::passenger::apache::centos::pre from rvm/passenger/apache/centos/pre into production
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/passenger/gem.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::passenger::gem from rvm/passenger/gem into production
Debug: importing '/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/manifests/passenger/apache/centos/post.pp' in environment production
Debug: Automatically imported rvm::passenger::apache::centos::post from rvm/passenger/apache/centos/post into production
Debug: Scope(Class[Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post]): Retrieving template rvm/passenger-apache-centos.conf.erb
Debug: template[/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/templates/passenger-apache-centos.conf.erb]: Bound template variables for /etc/puppet/modules/rvm/templates/passenger-apache-centos.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
Debug: template[/etc/puppet/modules/rvm/templates/passenger-apache-centos.conf.erb]: Interpolated template /etc/puppet/modules/rvm/templates/passenger-apache-centos.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPacman: file /usr/bin/pacman does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderOpenbsd: file pkg_add does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUrpmi: file urpmi does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUp2date: file /usr/sbin/up2date-nox does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSunfreeware: file pkg-get does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptrpm: file apt-get does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderNim: file /usr/sbin/nimclient does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPkg: file /usr/bin/pkg does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAix: file /usr/sbin/installp does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortupgrade: file /usr/sbin/pkg_info does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFreebsd: file /usr/sbin/pkg_add does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderZypper: file /usr/bin/zypper does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptitude: file /usr/bin/aptitude does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSun: file /usr/sbin/pkgadd does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPorts: file /usr/sbin/pkg_info does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: file /usr/bin/apt-get does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderHpux: file /usr/sbin/swlist does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFink: file /sw/bin/fink does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRug: file /usr/bin/rug does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortage: file /usr/bin/emerge does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPkgin: file pkgin does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderDpkg: file /usr/bin/dpkg does not exist
Debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roledel does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dsimport does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Rvm_gem::ProviderGem: file /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Rvm_gem::ProviderGem: file /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Rvm_system_ruby::ProviderRvm: file /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Rvm_system_ruby::ProviderRvm: file /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm does not exist
Debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
Debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
Debug: Creating default schedules
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'plugindest': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/lib", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"660", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/var/run/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"755", :path=>"/var/run/puppet", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"644", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"771", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/var/log/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :group=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/log/puppet", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"1755", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:ensure=>:file, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"640", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/etc/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/etc/puppet", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/client_data", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet]{:ensure=>:directory, :backup=>false, :loglevel=>:debug, :path=>"/var/lib/puppet", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
Debug: Finishing transaction 70336344903840
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/firewall/lib/facter/iptables.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/rvm/lib/facter/rvm_installed.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1361001784'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seedrubydownload/before: requires Class[Installruby]
Debug: /Stage[req-install]/before: requires Stage[rvm-install]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Installrvm/Rvm::System_user[vagrant]/Exec[/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G rvm vagrant]/require: requires User[vagrant]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Installrvm/Rvm::System_user[vagrant]/Exec[/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G rvm vagrant]/require: requires Group[rvm]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]/require: requires Rvm_gem[passenger]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]/require: requires Package[httpd]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]/require: requires Package[httpd-devel]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]/require: requires Package[mod_ssl]
Debug: /Stage[rvm-install]/Rvm::Dependencies/require: requires Class[Rvm::Dependencies::Centos]
Debug: /Stage[rvm-install]/Rvm::System/Exec[system-rvm]/require: requires Class[Rvm::Dependencies]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Installpassenger/require: requires Class[Installruby]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf]/require: requires Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Installruby/require: requires Class[Installrvm]
Debug: /Stage[rvm-install]/before: requires Stage[main]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[rubygems-source]: Autorequiring Group[rvm]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[ruby-source]: Autorequiring Group[rvm]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[yaml-source]: Autorequiring Group[rvm]
Debug: /Schedule[daily]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[monthly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[hourly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[never]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[weekly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: /Schedule[puppet]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
Debug: Prefetching yum resources for package
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
Debug: Executing '/bin/rpm -qa --nosignature --nodigest --qf '%{NAME} %|EPOCH?{%{EPOCH}}:{0}| %{VERSION} %{RELEASE} %{ARCH}
''
Debug: Exec[system-rvm](provider=posix): Executing 'bash -c '/usr/bin/curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer -o /tmp/rvm-installer ;                 chmod +x /tmp/rvm-installer ;                 rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin rvm_man_path=/usr/local/rvm/man /tmp/rvm-installer --version latest ;                 rm /tmp/rvm-installer''
Debug: Executing 'bash -c '/usr/bin/curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer -o /tmp/rvm-installer ;                 chmod +x /tmp/rvm-installer ;                 rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin rvm_man_path=/usr/local/rvm/man /tmp/rvm-installer --version latest ;                 rm /tmp/rvm-installer''
Notice: /Stage[rvm-install]/Rvm::System/Exec[system-rvm]/returns: executed successfully
Debug: /Stage[rvm-install]/Rvm::System/Exec[system-rvm]: The container Class[Rvm::System] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Class[Rvm::System]: The container Stage[rvm-install] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Executing '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p374 do gem list --local passenger$'
Debug: Executing '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p374 do gem install -v 3.0.19 --include-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri passenger'
Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p374 do gem install -v 3.0.19 --include-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri passenger' returned 1: Ruby ruby-1.9.3-p374 is not installed.

Error: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Gem/Rvm_gem[passenger]/ensure: change from absent to 3.0.19 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p374 do gem install -v 3.0.19 --include-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri passenger' returned 1: Ruby ruby-1.9.3-p374 is not installed.

Notice: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]: Dependency Rvm_gem[passenger] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/Exec[passenger-install-apache2-module]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf]: Dependency Rvm_gem[passenger] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Passenger::Apache::Centos::Post/File[/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[rubygems-source]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}1376a258d43c53750a8df30e67853e10'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[rubygems-source]: The container Class[Seed-ruby-download] will propagate my refresh event
Notice: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[ruby-source]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}944e73eba9ee9e1f2647ff32ec0b14b2'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[ruby-source]: The container Class[Seed-ruby-download] will propagate my refresh event
Notice: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[yaml-source]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Seed-ruby-download/File[yaml-source]: The container Class[Seed-ruby-download] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Class[Seed-ruby-download]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Exec[/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G rvm vagrant](provider=posix): Executing check '/bin/cat /etc/group | grep rvm | grep vagrant'
Debug: Executing '/bin/cat /etc/group | grep rvm | grep vagrant'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Installrvm/Rvm::System_user[vagrant]/Exec[/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G rvm vagrant]/unless: rvm:x:503:vagrant
Debug: Executing '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm list strings'
Debug: Executing '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p374'
Debug: Executing '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm alias create default ruby-1.9.3-p374'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Installruby/Rvm_system_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p374]/ensure: created
Debug: /Stage[main]/Installruby/Rvm_system_ruby[ruby-1.9.3-p374]: The container Class[Installruby] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Class[Installruby]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Finishing transaction 70336356537940
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 0.01 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 287.29 seconds
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rrddir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]{:ensure=>:directory, :group=>"puppet", :backup=>false, :owner=>"puppet", :loglevel=>:debug, :mode=>"750", :path=>"/var/lib/puppet/rrd", :links=>:follow}'
Debug: Finishing transaction 70336344986940
Debug: Received report to process from twdev01
Debug: Processing report from twdev01 with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
[root@twdev01 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further research, I found others have had this same issue..

https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm/issues/57

and it is already fixed:

https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm/pull/60

... but not integrated, so just apply the fix above, which involves editing `rvm/manifests/passenger/gem.pp` and make it look like:

```ruby
class rvm::passenger::gem($ruby_version, $version) {
  rvm_gem {
    "passenger":
      ensure       => $version,
      require => Rvm_system_ruby["${ruby_version}"],
      ruby_version => $ruby_version;
  }
}
```